# How can I have two editable and updatable DataGridViews bounded to a list and sub-list?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, bindinglist

I have a `List<Input>` named `listInput` that contains property of type a `List<class>` named `friends`:

```
List<Input> listInput=new List<Input>();
BindingList<Input> blInput;
BindingSource bsInput;

public class Input
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Friend> friends{ get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have two `DataGridView` controls, named `dgInput`and `dgFriends`.
`dgInput` is bound to a `BindingList` like this:

```
blInput = new BindingList<Input>(listInput);
bsInput = new BindingSource(blInput, null);
dgInput.DataSource = bsInput;
```

`dgInput` is **editable** and **updatable** at run-time after user changes any cell on `dgInput`.

The question is: how can I bind `dgFriends` to sublist `friends`, so that it will automatically update when the `dgInput` curretn Row changes?
It's also important that `dgFriens` can be updated when an User changes any cell on `dgFriends` (the properties of `listInput` must preserve the changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

- The first DataGridView uses the BindingSource you defined. The DataSource of this BindingSource is set to the `List<Input>` collection. This DGV can only show the `Name` property from the `List<Input>`, since you cannot present Rows containing both single values and collections of values.
  The `DataMember` of the BindingSource must be empty (or null): if you set `Name` as `DataMember`, you'll get an array of `Char` as a result instead of a string.
- A second BindingSource is created: its DataSource is set to the existing BindingSource. In this case, the `DataMember` is set explicitly to the `Friends` property, which represents a `List<class>` objects (a single object that represents a collection that will provide the data to the Rows of the second DGV).

This generates an active binding (a relationship) between the two BindingSource objects: when the first [`BindingSource.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current) object changes, the second BindingSource will follow, showing its `Current` object (the `List<Friend>` linked to the current `Name` property).

All properties of the two classes are editable.

**Note:**
I've implemented the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface in the `Input` class to notify changes of the `Name` property: it's not strictly required (or, it' not required at all) in this context, but you may want to have it there, you'll quite probably need it later.

```
List<Input> listInput = new List<Input>();
BindingSource bsInput = null;

public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bsInput = new BindingSource(listInput, "");
    var bsFriends = new BindingSource(bsInput, "Friends");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bsInput;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = bsFriends;
}

public class Input : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string m_Name = string.Empty;

    public string Name {
        get => m_Name;
        set { m_Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Name));
        }
    }
    public List<Friend> Friends { get; set; } = new List<Friend>();

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class Friend {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: DataGridView Double BindingSource]

Sample object initialization, for testing:

```
listInput.AddRange(new[] {
    new Input() {
        Name = "Name One", Friends = new List<Friend>() {
            new Friend () { FirstName = "First", LastName = "Friend of One"},
            new Friend () { FirstName = "Second", LastName = "Friend of One"},
            new Friend () { FirstName = "Third", LastName = "Friend of One"},
        }
    },
    new Input() {
        Name = "Name Two", Friends = new List<Friend>() {
            new Friend () { FirstName = "First", LastName = "Friend of Two"},
            new Friend () { FirstName = "Second", LastName = "Friend of Two"},
            new Friend () { FirstName = "Third", LastName = "Friend of Two"},
        }
    },
    new Input() {
        Name = "Name Three", Friends = new List<Friend>() {
            new Friend () { FirstName = "First", LastName = "Friend of Three"},
            new Friend () { FirstName = "Second", LastName = "Friend of Three"},
            new Friend () { FirstName = "Third", LastName = "Friend of Three"},
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimi for quick and clear answer , I try this solution in my main code and I'll tell the result, thank you again for edit my question context, sorry about my bad english writing :|

Comment: Sure, no problem. Test what you need to test. If you have issues, let me know.

Comment: in this case if user enter new name in last row (empty row) in `dataGridView1` and then fill `dataGridView2` new row, those new values doesn't save in listInput and will be lost if user leave last row, and that is my problem

Comment: That's because the `Input` class doesn't create a new `List<Friend>` when a new instance is created. That's very simple edit: `public List<Friend> friends { get; set; } = new List<Friend>();`. I've already updated the code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jimi , my problem solved , and that was exactly what I looking for.